# Why is npm publish telling me the package doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, npm-publish

I'm trying to upload an npm package to a GitLab registry for the first time. I set the scope and the npm config entries according to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/), but when I execute `npm publish`, I get the following error:

```
npm notice Publishing to https://git.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/123/packages/npm/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://git.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/123/packages/npm/@myscope%2fmyproject
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@myscope/myproject@1.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

So I try to publish it, and the error says it doesn't exist and that I should publish it...what?!

From the last two lines it looks like the error is meant for an installation failure, but I have definitely used `npm publish`. Also, in the `PUT` command, the final slash between scope and project name is replaced with `%2f`. No idea why that happened and why it happened nowhere else, but maybe that is a symptom of the underlying issue?

Comment: Maybe an authorization issue? Are you sure the token you're using has permission to the package registry?

Comment: @sytech The token has complete API access, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was my own fault. When executing `npm config set @foo:registry https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/`, I put in the group ID instead of the project ID in the place of `<your_project_id>`. We use the group only for the package registry project, so I got them confused.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you changed to get this working? ` I put in the ID of the Group and not the project I wanted to publish to` where did you enter this ID?

Comment: @Pete I edited my answer. I hope it's clearer now.